# Java HttpServer can't handle Requests for Context "/"

Tags: java, httpserver

I am currently setting up a Java HttpServer. It is working fine except for one thing:
Whenever I set the HttpContext to "/", it can not handle the request and sais: "***500 Internal Server Error***
No handler for context". This is the only thing which is not working, everything else was working fine.

```
private static WOP instance;
private WebServer webServer;

private WOP() {
    webServer = new WebServer(8080);
    HttpContext httpContext = webServer.getHttpServer().createContext("/");
    httpContext.setHandler(this::handleRequest);
    webServer.getHttpServer().start();
}

private void handleRequest(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
    String response = "Hi there!";
    httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.getBytes().length);//response code and length
    OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
    os.write(response.getBytes());
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: I was able to get your code to work, pretty much as you have it there, I set up the server like this.  HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);

Comment: hmm. When I do it like this, it is still not working. And the WebServer-class is doing exactly what you've done in your snippet.

Comment: I think your issue must be external to the code. It works on Ubuntu 19 with openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15, OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)